# Is it grammatically correct to "predict" something from the past?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, tenses

For example, would "I predict how the Mayans lived for a daily living" be correct?

Comment: This isn't a question of grammar; it's a question of semantics or more likely pragmatics.  The sentence is grammatically fine.  If you mean "would people see this usage as natural or problematic" ... well, I personally think predicting the unknown from the known is fine regardless of time period, but others may not, so you may prefer to play it safe and say "analyze" instead.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it. You are merely predicting the confirmation of something you already suspect.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This could be an interesting question. As you say, you cannot predict something that has already happened. But you can predict *establishing the truth about* something that happened in the past, if the establishing will happen in the future. So it depends on context. I think your question would benefit if you could provide more context for us.

Comment: You *can* predict that you’d *find* (future) a particular characteristic about the past.

Comment: @Lawrence If I understand right, you mean something like "I predict that one day JFK's assassination will be proven to have been a cover-up".

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes, that's the structure I was referring to (I'm not commenting on the content :) ). *Predict* is inherently about something in the future, so it needs a future event even though the event might relate to the past.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty liberal with the use of words, but you can see from the following definitions that the word "predict" doesn't quite fit what you're saying, that is, if I understand your question correctly.

> v.tr. To state, tell about, or make known in advance, especially on
>   the basis of special knowledge
>  v.intr. To foretell something.
>   [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/predict)
>
> vb (tr; may take a clause as object) to state or make a declaration
>   about in advance, esp on a reasoned basis; foretell 
> [Collins English
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/predict)
>
> v.t.
>   1. to declare or tell in advance; foretell.
>  v.i.
>   2. to foretell the future; make a prediction.
>  [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/predict)
>
> : to declare or indicate in advance especially : foretell on the basis
>   of observation, experience, or scientific reason
>  [Merriam-Webster
>   Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predict)
>
> verb
>  to say that an event or action will happen in the future,
>   especially as a result of knowledge or experience:
>  [Cambridge
>   Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/predict)
>
> verb
>  [with object]
>  Say or estimate that (a specified thing)
>   will happen in the future or will be a consequence of something.
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/predict)
>
> verb [transitive]
>  to say what you think will happen in the
>   future
>  [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/predict)
>
> (transitive) To make a prediction: to forecast, foretell, or estimate
>   a future event on the basis of knowledge and reasoning; to prophesy a
>   future event on the basis of mystical knowledge or power.
>   [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predict)
>
> A prediction (Latin præ-, "before," and dicere, "to say"), or
>   forecast, is a statement about a future event.
>   [Wikipedia article on prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction)

For perspective from answers already answering this question, I provide this Quora link, [Is it possible to predict the past](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-predict-the-past)

There are search results for "predict the past", I'm unsure what to make of these. Some are phrases like "it's impossible to predict the past" or "predict" is in what are called scare quotes, which shows the writer wishes to draw attention to the word as possibly a misuse. However there seem to many genuine positive results.

For example there is an article on New Scientist magazine online that uses it:

> The validity of models can be tested against climate history. If they
>   can predict the past (which the best models are pretty good at) they
>   are probably on the right track for predicting the future – and indeed
>   have successfully done so.
>   [Climate myths: We can’t trust computer models](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn11649-climate-myths-we-cant-trust-computer-models/)

I would personally use a word like "infer" or "theorise" to describe your hypothesis of how the Maya lived in the past. The word "hypothesise" itself would also fit.

Also an important point, see the first comment to your question by DanBron about the difference between grammar and semantics.

Comment: In the climate model example, ‘predict the past’ is really just a shorthand for ‘predict a future which we humans happen to already know lies in the past’, so it makes sense. The computer model is in fact predicting the future as far as it knows – it’s just being fed data which happens to originate in the past. Actually _predicting_ something with no hint of futureness doesn’t make any sense: “I predict that I went shopping yesterday” would be fairly universally considered unacceptable, I’d wager.

Answer (score 0):

Predict:
-(transitive) To make a prediction: to forecast, foretell, or estimate a future event on the basis of knowledge and reasoning; to prophesy a future event on the basis of mystical knowledge or power. (*cited from wiktionary*)
-As you may see 'future' is intrinsic to the definition of 'predict'. 
-You cannot predict the past. You can say **'I predicted that Germany would win the 2014 world cup'**. Meaning your prediction turned out to be true. But as for your sentence **I can speculate/speculated/can presume  how mayans lived their daily lives'**.
-Paleontologists 'predict' the structure of a dinosaur skeletion when there aren't enough pieces available but that's not always how the dinosaur skeleton turns out to be.The skeletal structure has been already determined i.e when it was born,reached adulthood etc.  Prediction can only be made about contemporary prospects of a furture outcome.Like how the skeletal structure of a certain dinosaur may turn out. 
-I think the correct verb would be either deduce/assume/presume/speculate etc synonyms to those in accordance to the context.